# What is this noise on 6m?

Tags: rfi, noise

I'm trying to figure out what an S8 noise source is on my 6m band. I already turned off all the breakers in my house, and it only reduced to S7.5 noise, so there is a small interference from my home, but it's almost certainly external at this point.

Any idea what might generate an RFI pattern as seen in the attached waterfall? This is a 10MHz bandwidth view around the 6m band.[image: waterfall view of RFI]

Comment: does it completely go away if you disconnect the antenna?

Comment: plus, if it's external, at least knowing which country you're in would help determine which *legal* interferers might be there. There's instances where people looked on a map and were able to pinpoint a possible source, but that's of course coupled to giving up information on your *precise* location on the internetz.

Comment: (for example: that 6m band also being legal for military comms where I am) (another example, the 47-52 MHz range is allowed for wind radars; but you'd probably need to be close to a large meterological antenna system. If someone familiar with the locations of these saw your position was not far from that, it would be a nice clue)

Comment: (another thing to mentally prepare yourself for: even *if* you figured out what this is, it might simply be impossible to make go away, *even* if it's a device going outside its emission limits. If I look at the waterfall below your image, this looks like something not optimized for frequency stability, i.e., not an intentional transmitter, which has some strongly periodic signal with sidelobes. It might be some not-too-complex digital communication link's harmonics, for example. For a simple switch-mode supply's harmonics, it's not "sinc-y" enough, but it might be designed for low noise.)

Comment: And another trick for the future, but one that I **strongly** recommend: your computer's operating system (Windows?) has a functionality for making a screen shot, and that will be much easier to take and much easier to read than taking a picture of your screen with a camera.